# "Мы с Тамарой ходим парой"

Tags: грамотная-речь

А, если серьезно, хотелось бы узнать, грамотен ли оборот "мы с кем-то", когда речь идет о двоих — те же самые "мы с Тамарой"? Ведь, если "мы", то предполагается, что, кроме Тамары, имеются еще как минимум двое. А, если один, то не грамотнее ли будет говорить "я с Тамарой"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Местоимение МЫ подчеркивает равноправность субъектов. И поскольку там даже уточняется - парой, то только МЫ. Мы с сестрой ездили. (Вместе, на равных) Я с сестрой ездил.(Я ездил, сестра при мне. Или наоборот).

Answer (score 1):

Я с Тамарой хожу парой? Наверно, допустимо. А вот "Я с Тамарой санитар (санитары?)" - уже нет. Поскольку действуют два лица, сказуемое как-то привычнее звучит во множественном числе, особенно если это сказуемое выражено существительным. С другой стороны, "Я с товарищем приходил к тебе" не режет ухо. Может, есть какое-то правило. Думаю, что olsa даст исчерпывающий ответ.

Answer (score 1):

> > > грамотен ли оборот "мы с кем-то", когда речь идет о двоих — те же самые "мы с Тамарой"?

Грамотен. Просто грамматика не позволяет использовать местоимения единственного числа, как это @Ларf и @Элен уже сказали. Таким образом, в данном сочетании "мы" означает не некоторые "мы" плюс некто третий, с которым "мы с", а "я и некто второй".

Сложнее ответить на вопрос, чем эта форма, "мы с ним", лучше "я и он". Я очень сомневаюсь, что первый вариант более "равноправный". Скорее уж дело в другом.
"Мы с ним" означает действие общее, парой, а "я и он" - по отдельности.
Таким образом, я "Мы с Тамарой ходим парой" безусловно правильно (совместное действие), а вот "Мы с Тамарой - санитары" неудачно, свойство индивидуальное, точнее было бы "Я и Тамара - санитары".